# Embedding an FTP Server in an App

Tags: android, ftp, ftp-server

I wanted to run an FTP server via an Android app, are there any open source FTP servers available so that I can use them in my app. The FTP server will be run as service, as per the settings set by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Colorado FTP](http://cftp.coldcore.com/) - open source FTP server in Java. First one from Google on "open source ftp server in java".

Comment: Techeretic, was your xp successfull? I've looked through colorado but it fails...(

Answer (score 0):

also busybox ftpd (when it is available). I wish I knew it 3 days ago :(

```
    /system/bin/busybox --install -s /system/xbin
    /system/xbin/tcpsvd -E 0.0.0.0 21 /system/xbin/ftpd /data/ourFolder/ -w
```